# In SAS, how do I find correlations along a single column of data by another variable?

Tags: sas

Let's say I have daily stock returns for 100 stocks in 1990. I want to calculate the correlation matrix of the returns of all these stocks. But instead of having 100 columns of returns data with 1 column for each stock, I have 1 column of returns data with a second column of ticker symbols and a 3rd column of dates.

(Note that these stocks might change from year to year, but I want to calculate the correlations of returns in each year.)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Transpose your data to create a variable for each stock and then use proc corr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just transpose the data to get one row for each day and one column for each stock:

```
proc transpose data=have out=want;
  by date;
  id symbol;
run;
```

Then proceed from there.